# Python: Usar una función como tipo

Tags: python, graphql

Actualmente tengo este error

```
\n Invalid GraphQL Query:\n Error Message: {'errors': [{'message': 'Expected type EditionRarity!, found \"EDITION_RARITY_STANDARD\". Did you mean the enum value EDITION_RARITY_STANDARD, EDITION_RARITY_LEGENDARY, EDITION_RARITY_RARE, EDITION_RARITY_NIL, or EDITION_RARITY_UNIQUE?', 'locations': [{'line': 1, 'column': 98}], 'extensions': {'code': 'GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED'}}, {'message': 'Expected type EditionType!, found \"EDITION_TYPE_AVATAR_WEARABLE\". Did you mean the enum value EDITION…, or EDITION_DESIGN_SLOT_SHOES?', 'locations': [{'line': 1, 'column': 173}], 'extensions': {'code': 'GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED'}}], 'data': None}\n Query: mutation{addEdition(input:{name: \"fristTestAsset\",collectionFlowID: 1,onchainMetadata: {rarity: \"EDITION_RARITY_STANDARD\",type: \"EDITION_TYPE_AVATAR_WEARABLE\",designSlot: \"EDITION_DESIGN_SLOT_HELMET\",avatarWearableSKU: \"2022-1TS-collOne-edi2\",},idempotencyKey: \"03390450cdc641e1ba361bb06e9429fc\",}){success,flowID}}\n "
```

Por lo que puedo ver, es un error de tipo

Este es el código que tengo en el modelo:

```
rarity: Attribute = Attribute(key="rarity", value_type="str")
celebrity: Attribute = Attribute(key="celebrity", value_type="str")
artist: Attribute = Attribute(key="artist", value_type="str")
edition_type: Attribute = Attribute(key="type", value_type="str")
design_slot: Attribute = Attribute(key="designSlot", value_type="str")
publisher: Attribute = Attribute(key="publisher", value_type="str")
trademark: Attribute = Attribute(key="trademark", value_type="str")
avatar_wearable_sku: Attribute = Attribute(
    key="avatarWearableSKU", value_type="str"
)
```

Antes, tenía unos Enums hardcodeados y entonces no había problema, pero ahora hay una función para cada uno de esos 3 campos que causan problemas que genera de forma dinámica los Enums.

Entonces lo que no estoy pudiendo resolver, es como puedo usar esas funciones para setear el value_type.

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Listo, gracias por las recomendaciones